# Test GraphQL endpoint with PactV3 fails (PactV3 500 Internal Server Error)

Tags: angular, jestjs, pact

I try to create a Pact on the consumer side with Pact-JS.
In PactJS v3, the `.withQuery` method seemed to be removed and generall support for GraphQL testing is [not available](https://docs.pact.io/implementation_guides/javascript/docs/graphql).
Tough it should be possible to either use the mentioned `GraphQLInteraction` interaction or to test the plain body of the POST request I guess, but I couldn't figure out how, since as soon as I add a body to the `.requestWith` method, I get the error:

`Http failure response for http://... 500 Internal Server Error`

The problem is the body property in the `withRequest` method. Without the property the mock server throws no error but the Pact of course doesn't include a request body and therefore is quite useless.

```
.withRequest({
  method: 'POST',
  path: `/product/graphql`,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Accept: "application/json",
  },

  /*
   * Adding a body to the request fails with:
   * `Http failure response for http://127.0.0.1:4000/product/graphql: 500 Internal Server Error`
   *
   * The goal is to have the request body in the created Pact, because without it, it is
   * quite useless.
   */
  // body: requestBody,                                     // fails
  // body: MatchersV3.like(requestBody),                    // fails
  // body: MatchersV3.string(JSON.stringify(requestBody)),  // fails
})
```

*I created a [GIT repository](https://github.com/j0wey/pact-js-test-example) with a minimal example for the attempt with the body.
As Karma support was deprecated with Pact v10, the repo also includes the switch to Jest.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the `operationName` from the request.

The logs hint at this:

```
[2022-08-13T11:48:06Z DEBUG pact_matching] --> Mismatches: [BodyMismatch { path: "$", expected: Some(b"[\"query\",\"variables\"]"), actual: Some(b"[\"operationName\",\"query\",\"variables\"]"), mismatch: "Expected a Map with keys query, variables but received one with keys operationName, query, variables" }]
[2022-08-13T11:48:06Z DEBUG pact_mock_server::hyper_server] Request did not match: Request did not match - HTTP Request ( method: POST, path: /product/graphql, query: None, headers: Some({"Content-Type": ["application/json"], "Accept": ["application/json"]}), body: Present(68 bytes, application/json) )    0) $ -> Expected a Map with keys query, variables but received one with keys operationName, query, variables
```

The correct query to send as the body is:

```js
const requestBody = { "operationName": "product", "query":"{ product { data { idProduct name } } }", "variables": null }
```

There is an issue in Pact JS which is not helpfully printing this for you, as the test itself is failing. The next release of Pact JS should print a (more helpful) error like this for you:

```
  ● Product Service › Given there are already some products in the database › should get a list of existing products

    Test failed for the following reasons:

      Mock server failed with the following mismatches:

        0) The following request was incorrect:

                POST /product/graphql

                 1.0 Expected a Map with keys query, variables but received one with keys operationName, query, variables
```

Comment: Did you test this on Linux? My problem is, that I don't get any error log at all (on Windows) besides the mentioned internal server error. Will check this asap. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you very much, I can confirm that this solves the problem. Though I don't agree that this is the correct behaviour. GraphQL docs say, that [`operationName`](https://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/#post-request) is optional as long as only one operation is present. Am I missing something? Otherwise, I would create a bug item.

Comment: For anyone interessted, I guess this is the issue and PR for the new log format Matthew showed https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-js/issues/909

Comment: Pact doesn't need `operationName`, it just needs your mock to match the implementation. It was complaining, because your client (implementation) _is sending_ `operationName` but your test didn't expect it to. So Pact threw an error saying "Your request didn't match what you said it would do". We fixed the test to match the actual behaviour.

Comment: Thank you again for clarification. I had completely overlooked that.

Answer (score 0):

As a practical complement to Matthew's correct answer:

**Workaround for `Http failure response for http://... 500 Internal Server Error`**

As said this will be fixed in a future Pact version. As long as you need it right away you can copy the changes from [a current PR](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-js/pull/920):

```
// /node_modules/@pact-foundation/pact/src/v3/pact.js
// replace the `executeTest` function with the following (tested with Pact v10.1.0 and v10.1.1)

// !! of course this will likely break the executeTest funtion in a later release when there are updates !!

  PactV3.prototype.executeTest = function (testFn) {
        return __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function () {
            var scheme, host, port, server, val, e_1, matchingResults_1, error, matchingResults, success, error;
            return __generator(this, function (_a) {
                switch (_a.label) {
                    case 0:
                        scheme = this.opts.tls ? 'https' : 'http';
                        host = this.opts.host || '127.0.0.1';
                        port = this.pact.createMockServer(host, this.opts.port, this.opts.tls);
                        server = { port: port, url: "".concat(scheme, "://").concat(host, ":").concat(port), id: 'unknown' };
                        _a.label = 1;
                    case 1:
                        _a.trys.push([1, 3, , 4]);
                        return [4 /*yield*/, testFn(server)];
                    case 2:
                        val = _a.sent();
                        return [3 /*break*/, 4];
                    case 3:
                        e_1 = _a.sent();
                        matchingResults_1 = this.pact.mockServerMismatches(port);
                        error = 'Test failed for the following reasons:';
                        error += "\n\n  ".concat((0, display_1.generateMockServerError)(matchingResults_1, '\t'));
                        this.cleanup(false, server);
                        throw new Error((error += "\n\n Original exception: \n".concat(e_1)));
                    case 4:
                        matchingResults = this.pact.mockServerMismatches(port);
                        success = this.pact.mockServerMatchedSuccessfully(port);
                        // Feature flag: allow missing requests on the mock service
                        if (!success && (0, display_1.filterMissingFeatureFlag)(matchingResults).length > 0) {
                            error = 'Test failed for the following reasons:';
                            error += "\n\n  ".concat((0, display_1.generateMockServerError)(matchingResults, '\t'));
                            this.cleanup(false, server);
                            return [2 /*return*/, Promise.reject(new Error(error))];
                        }
                        this.cleanup(true, server);
                        return [2 /*return*/, val];
                }
            });
        });
    };
```